# The system is running on low graphics error

Tags: command-line

I have read on multiple threads that I can get into a terminal and login using failsafeX by using ctrl+alt+f1. The problem I am having with this is whenever I hit ctrl+alt+f1 it pulls up a terminal like screen but its filled with GTKDialog errors and errors saying I am trying to use without transient parent and it doesn't allow me to type any commands or login. Is there any way to fix this so I can login and run the nvidia update commands?

When the 'terminal' window actually opens it doesn't allow me to type in commands it just moves on to the next line without executing anything and doesn't allow me to login or give me the option to.

Comment: That is the page I viewed earlier but when I try to open the terminal, it doesn't actually allow me to type in commands or login it just types below all the messages and after I hit enter it just goes to the next line without actually doing anything. @karel

Comment: That's what is called a black screen like this question: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) however that question isn't specific for low graphics mode so there is a separate question for the low graphics topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you are comfortable running terminal commands, perhaps it would be fruitful to try booting directly into recovery mode, which will bypass starting the graphics server on boot.

This can be done by hitting ESC immediately after the system finishes its BIOS/POST output after a restart. This should bring up the GRUB bootloader menu where you can choose to start your system using the latest kernel and in recovery mode. Booting this way will present a diagnostics menu, where you can first, enable networking (which should give you internet access and put your filesystem into read/write mode), followed by the option to drop to a root command line.

Once networking is enabled, the recovery mode root command prompt should allow you to run the apt commands needed to fix your nvidia driver.